# Create a meta box which displays an image from the gallery in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gallery, meta-boxes

I have a custom post type with multiple custom text fields (meta boxes), and I need to create a custom field like the box for the featured image. Meaning a field which will be used to select an image from the media gallery and save it for display.
I don't have any custom fields WordPress plugins.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var frame;
  $('.image-upload').on( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (frame) {
      frame = null;
    }

    frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Frame title',
      button: {
        text: 'Frame button text'
      },
      multiple: false
    });

    frame.on( 'select', function() {
      var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      var url = attachment.url;
      var id = attachment.id;
    });

    frame.open();
  });
```

Put this inside admin js file. Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: The admin.js file of my theme ? And can I do it only for my custom post type ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean admin-side javascript file. It could be any of them, even one dedicated for your custom post type page.